# JFrame, removed and created JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JFrame in which I create and remove panels from external classes, problem is, when I move back and forth (delete and create panels several times, I don't want references to all the panels, all the data that should be passed on (frame and boolean [soon to be implemented]) will be in constructor) it moves whole content downwards.

I'm using `GridBagLayout`, perhaps that has some hidden issues.  I don't want to use CardLayout, so please don't recommend it.

Why is it doing so and what should I do to stop it?

Code

```
deleteContract = new JButton("Usuń kontrakt");
        deleteContract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                ACDeleteContract ACDeleteContract = new ACDeleteContract(frame);
                removeAll();
            add(ACDeleteContract);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    deleteContract.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    c.gridy = 2;
    menu.add(deleteContract, c);

    back = new JButton("Powrót");
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           ACMenu menu = new ACMenu(frame);
           removeAll();
           add(menu);
           revalidate();
           repaint();
       } 
    });
```

Comment: *"I dont want to use CardLayout, so please dont recommend it."*  I don't want to spend time helping you to implement silly requirements.  Given `CardLayout` is the sensible & obvious answer to this requirement, why neglect using it?

Comment: Well then, I could have been wrong. I have external classes for all the JPanels and somehow I didn't think I could swap between them with action listeners. Perhaps I should just pass on as an argument the cardLayout and reference to it in those action listeners.

Comment: Alright, I managed to do it, works fine, I've been mistaken, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Andrew Thompson guided me to the good path which I didn't want to take earlier.

For future generations a couple of hints :D.

To do in your frame

```
CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
    cardPanel.setLayout(cards);

    ACReadContract ACReadContract = new ACReadContract(cards, cardPanel);
    //your external JPanel classes with arguments such as above
    ACMenu ACMenu = new ACMenu(cards, cardPanel);

    cardPanel.add(ACMenu, "Menu");
    cardPanel.add(ACReadContract, "ReadContract");
    //naming and adding them for easy moving between them

    //adding this to frame
    add(cardPanel);
```

In external classes (start of constructor, classes should extend JPanel)

```
private JPanel menu, cardPanel1;
private CardLayout cardLayout1;

public ACMenu(CardLayout cardLayout, JPanel cardPanel) {

    cardLayout1=cardLayout;
    cardPanel1 = cardPanel;
```

In action listeners in external class

```
cardLayout1.next(cardPanel1);
```

or

```
cardLayout1.show(cardPanel1, "ReadContract");
```

I hope I've helped a bit those that have similar problem.